# R: "z" must be a numeric matrix

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here for making 3 plots in R: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

```
  library(plotly)
    # volcano is a numeric matrix that ships with R
    fig <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano)
    fig <- fig %>% add_surface()
    
    fig
```

I tried to replicate this example with my own data:

```
#generate data
a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,5,5)
c = rnorm(100,5,10)
d = data.frame(a,b,c)

# plot
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~d)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```

However this produces the following error:

```
Error: 'z' must be a numeric matrix
```

I tried changing "d" to a matrix:

```
d = as.matrix(d)
```

But I get the same error.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Using `fig <- plot_ly(z = ~as.matrix(d));fig <- fig %>% add_surface();fig` doesn't give the error.

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you please explain the logic behind this? Why does as.matrix() have to be used in the plot_ly() function ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the error message the value for `z` axis needs to be a numeric matrix. The default data `volcano` is also a matrix. So you could do :

```
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~as.matrix(d))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer @Ronak Shah! If possible, can you please take a look at this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996674/r-plot-axis-display-values-larger-than-the-original-data ? Thank you